# Nested attributes after_update changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested attributes from 3 different models. Updating models through single form.

I do get attribute_name_changed? in before_save, however same is not available in after_save.

I need to trigger email on after save.

#### Code examples

```
class Company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :configurations
  after_save :callback_after_save
  before_save :callback_before_save

  def callback_before_save
    self.configuration.field_was # This gives old values as expected
  end

  def callback_after_save
    self.configuration.field_was # This doesn't work
  end
end
```

Comment: can you put some examples of your code please?

Comment: The `attribute_was` method will only give you the last persisted value, as I think you know. What you're trying to do will not work. In order for other people to be able to help you, we would have to know what you need to do ("trigger email" doesn't say anything to me) and why you need to do it.

Comment: Email trigger should only happen after_update (just to be sure that database operation was successful) The email should consist of both old and new values. Since i have applied after_save on just the company model, i am trying to get attribute_was for the configuration model as well, which isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its actually possible to do what i was trying above.

Alternative i had to do was store changes in before save and use it in after_save